# Iterating over files in directory to find content

Tags: java, file, iteration

How would i be able to iterate over a list of different files (in a certain directory) and filter across a List, then if the certain string is found it would return the file it found it in.

```
Eg: Files are '344-444.yml, 555-646.yml and 996-666.yml
File 344-444.yml contains:
hobby:
- football
- hockey
- custom
```

if custom is found, the first match it finds to return the file name, eg `344-444.yml`.

Thanks!

Comment: Does [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154488/how-do-i-iterate-through-the-files-in-a-directory-in-java)  help you?

Comment: @Aziuth not exactly, i wish to also get the contents of the file searching through a List<String> for my certain string and then finally return the file name.

Comment: Did you write any code?  Did you do any searches for the functionality you desire?

Comment: Yup @VGR, i have found around actually listing my files but i wish to grab each files contents and iterate through the list.

Comment: It sounds like you already know how to iterate over a list of files, then.  And it sounds like your real question is how to search a file for a list of words.  Which part of that is giving you difficulty?

Comment: There is a post for the exact same question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858966/search-files-by-text-content-inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your explanation of the objective is a bit unclear. However, I understood that at a certain point you will have your list of strings (the dictionary) and you have to seach each string on a specific file. A good algorithm for this is the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/aho-corasick-algorithm-pattern-searching/) which will give you complexity linear in the length of the file + number of occurences + length of dictionary. If the size of your dictionary is large, this is a huge time gain with respect to looking for one string at a time.